# autohotkey text replacement with variable

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to figure out a way to do text replacement with a variable if possible.

Basically let's say I have a string: `The Color is Red`

I can say `::color::The Color is Red` which will work, but now what if I want to be able to specify the color on demand. So if I typed `color blue` it would print out `The Color is Blue` instead.

Is there a way to do that? Or will I have to define all possible variations of my sentence in my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [parsing Loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm) (or a For Loop in an array) and the [Hotstring() function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm) to create the hotstrings dynamically:

```
colors := "Blue,Red,White"
Loop, parse, colors, `,
Hotstring(":*:" "color " A_Loopfield, "The Color is "  A_Loopfield, On)
```

The above code has to be placed in the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script, before the first hotkey, hotstring or return) otherwise the script can't create the hotstrings.